# Cheking multiple columns in a table with single select query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm passing a value to the database(Say-'gupta'). I want to compare this value with all the
columns present in the database table. If any column value matched the particular value then
I want to simply print that row in my Php Page.
Is there any inbuilt function to do this using select query.If yes please tell me.
Remember i want to compare the passed value('gupta') with the multiple columns values in the database(corephp+mysql)

Comment: So ... what have you tried so far? Please show us your code.

Comment: echo $sql="select * from user where find_in_set('$form_id',firstname,lastname) ";

Comment: is this query is correct?

Comment: In this firstname andlastname are the database values...And form_id is the value which i'm passingto the DB

Answer (score 0):

USE LIKE along with OR. eg.

```
Select * from table where (col1 like '%gupta%') or (col2 like '%gupta%')
```

so any col matches your input word, this will return the row.

Comment: :) accept this as the answer if this worked (tick on the side).

Answer (score -1):

Just an idea

```
select * from TableName where "gupta" IN (ColumnOne,ColumnTwo,ColumnThree)
```